# Сменить локаль на ubuntu 20.04 x64 (18.04 x64)

Tags: ubuntu

Каким образом сменить locale на ubuntu 20.04 x64?

Comment: `localectl set-locale ru_RU.UTF-8`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первый шаг - проверить текущие языковые настройки системы. Для этого выполните команду locale без аргументов:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Измените настройки текущего языка системы. Для этого выполните следующую команду `dpkg-reconfigure`:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Затем выберите желаемый системный язык:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выберите, какой язык вы хотите использовать в качестве основного для всей системы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То что названо «желаемый системный язык» — это список генерируемых локалей.

Comment: и ручками то же самое можно сделать в `/etc/locale.gen` и `/etc/default/locale` соответственно, если кому-то интересно...

Comment: Я как-то просто руками через файл менял на Raspberry Pi с `gb` на `en`.